# The driver was unable to create a connection to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I'm programming in java SE and I get an error when trying to access to create a connection to mysql. I can connect to mysql, in fact, the error shows up when running a bucle.
What I do in this program is to check for a String in the table Colors of my database and if it finds nothing it creates this String in the table with an autoincrementing id.
It works fine, but after having checked it for a while it gives me the error.
I attach the image of the error and the code where I create the connection.
[image]

```
public Integer codiColor(String col){

    Integer codi=null;

    if(col.equals(""))
        return 1;

    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuari, password);//here is the error
        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT CODICOL FROM COLORES where COLOR ='"+col+"'";
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(sql);

            if(res.next()){
                codi = res.getInt("CODICOL");
            }
            try { res.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
            try { st.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        catch(SQLException s){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:\n"+s.getMessage(),
                  "ERROR.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        finally{
            try { con.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return codi;
}
```

This code is the one that checks if the color already exists or not.

**EDIT:**

```
url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.200:3306/mybbdd?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
```

Comment: check the no of opened sockets using netstat -an command and compare the limit with ulimit

Comment: I'm using Windows, is it possible to do that? Never done before

Comment: You are creating a new connection on each call, but it seems the old ones are not being properly disposed. You should probably use some kind of "persistent connection".

Comment: Isn't it enough by closing the connection? Well, I thought it was...

Comment: I would suppose that much too.. But seems not true if the error shows after multiple tries.

Comment: And how can I do a "persistent connection"?

Comment: @danibg seems like `con` is not a local variable, but maybe a property? you can check if it exists and is already connected. Or you might try to use local variable instead, maybe then close() would be enough? (I dont know java that well so maybe thats nonsense..)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, it means the same, but using local variables you work less efficiently as you create a new variable any time instead of changing the value of the general variable.

Comment: Thats micro-optimization and lets "last" value of con to be accessed anywhere else where it is visible even when it was closed and is not supposed to be used. "creating" a local variable in compiled language actually means that compiler makes some math with current stack etc as that variable will only be object reference, the object itself is still created each time in the called function. But objects referenced only by local variables may be disposed of differently as their lifespan is well known.

Comment: The stacktrace in the picture is illegible. Don't post pictures of text here. Pointless waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `con` is evidently a member variable where it should be a local variable. If this piece of code and others like it are called from multiple threads, a `con` value will be overwritten and therefore lost, so a connection leak will result. You will almost certainly also have other problems due to concurrent use of the connection. Make it a local variable.

NB you haven't needed the `Class.forName()` line since 2007. The close of the connection, statement, and result set would be redundant if you used try-with-resources. And you should use a prepared statement.

```
String sql = "SELECT CODICOL FROM COLORES where COLOR =?";
try (con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuari, password);
        PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ) {
        st.setObject(1, col);
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
        if(res.next()){
            codi = res.getInt("CODICOL");
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException s){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:\n"+s.getMessage(),
              "ERROR.",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code you giving a new connection on every call but you need to understand your OS allows you Only Limited Connection.
after cross Limit it will Not allow you to make another Connection.

i don't know what's your requirement but if you really need Connection

So better option is that you need to make Connection Pool. If user required a connection to do some task then user can Take Connection from connection Pool and after Work Finished user can return that connection to connection pool.

For Achieve this you need to Design Your Configuration File Or you need Design interface library interface and implement according to your Requirement.

Answer (score -1):

I find the way out. I googled the number the java error gave to me and I found that adding a registry key to be able to do more connections should work.
I first did it on the server, to allow more connections from clients but it didn't still work so I tried to do it on my computer and for now it works.
[This is the link from microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271)

Comment: You've moved the point at which the problem will occur. You haven't solved the problem.